# Is there any GUI based builder for URDF?

Tags: ros, urdf, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question is, I am a novice in ROS. I find the URDF builder by way of manually entering x, y and z values cumbersome. Is there any GUI builder - drag and drop where we concentrate on building the robot model visually faster? Any pointers to links where they explain how to specify x,y and z values easier?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280520/is-there-any-gui-based-builder-for-urdf?/) by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use solidworks or any other software for developing your Robot and then you can change this into URDF
here is the link :-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7X_p_KMwus&t=76s

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on 2018-01-23**:
Thank you. Editing the URDF file manually each time and then running it is so time consuming. I found the following link, which allows at least a web based interface to quickly edit and model your robot.

http://www.mymodelrobot.appspot.com/5674976526991360

Is there any tool like the link shown ?

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-23**:
That's amazing tool on online but if you not know how to create URDF how will you use this ?

**Comment by [dpakshimpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33391/dpakshimpo/) on 2018-01-23**:
Thanks. I understand the basics of URDF, what I find cumbersome is that the alignment of each of the links of the robots and links is time consuming and I am not getting any logic how to place for e.x, 1 box shape above another shape. If you know any tutorial which helps get a hang of it, let me kno

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-23**:
have you check the  :-  https://www.robotigniteacademy.com/
OR
you can check there Youtube channel :- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt6Lag-vv25fTX3e11mVY1Q
andyou can find every solution there , i think these videos and link will help you